# Set an SSIS package Package Parameter and execute it using the new Param value

Tags: powershell, ssis, azure-powershell

I have been trying to find the best way to set the connection string property configured inside of an SSIS package. I read that some of the system config parameters become exposed. The code below sets the parameter correctly, however, when I query the execution table, the package never runs with the altered parameter or connection string. (Perhaps someone could provide a solution or perhaps a better way to dynamically set a connection string in a package prior to execute() in powershell)

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::Load("Microsoft.SQLServer.Management.IntegrationServices, "+
"Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91, processorArchitecture=MSIL") | Out-Null
$sqlConnectionString = `
"Data Source=xxx;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
$sqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection $sqlConnectionString
$SSISNamespace = "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices"
$SSIS = New-Object $SSISNamespace".IntegrationServices" $sqlConnection
$catalog = $SSIS.Catalogs["SSISDB"]

$parameterName ="CM.ClientDB.InitialCatalog"

$paramValue ="[SomeDatabase0001]" # I have tried it with and without brackets []

$ssisPackage = $catalog.Folders["ProjectFolder"].Projects["Project"].Packages["Package.dtsx"]

Write-Output $ssisPackage.Parameters[$parameterName]

$ssisPackage.Parameters[$parameterName].Set([Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices.ParameterInfo+ParameterValueType]::Literal,$paramValue)
$ssisProject.Alter()

Write-Output $ssisPackage.Parameters[$parameterName]

try {
    $ssisPackage.Execute("false", $null)    
}
catch {
    Write-Output "Fail"
}
Write-Output "Done"
```

The output seems to indicate the value was set correctly.

```
Name                   : CM.ClientDB.InitialCatalog
...
DesignDefaultValue     : [SomeDatabase]
DefaultValue           :

Name                   : CM.ClientDB.InitialCatalog
DesignDefaultValue     : [SomeDatabase]
DefaultValue           : SomeDatabase0001

...
32
Done
```

And from what I can find in the ssisdb:

```
SELECT * from internal.execution_parameter_values where parameter_name='CM.ClientDB.InitialCatalog'

...(never changes)
paramater_name              paramater_value  
---------------             --------------
CM.ClientDB.InitialCatalog  [SomeDatabase]
CM.ClientDB.InitialCatalog  [SomeDatabase]
CM.ClientDB.InitialCatalog  [SomeDatabase]
CM.ClientDB.InitialCatalog  [SomeDatabase]
CM.ClientDB.InitialCatalog  [SomeDatabase]
...
```

Comment: Reading the PS, I don't see where `$ssisProject` came into being

Comment: @billinkc - Doh! That was the problem. It seems to look better when $ssisPackage.Alter() is called.

Answer (score 0):

After help from the comment above and some serious searching, I pieced together a solution.  Naturally, the build server does not have the SSIS Data Tools pack installed so some of the management pieces that worked on my machine failed when running a build pipeline in azure dev-ops. I found that I could feed the required assemblies in the root and load them from there. Not the ideal solution. I needed the package to run synchronously due to another build task awaiting its output. I found that there are a few overloads to execute and one lets you override the run-time parameters, including SYNCHRONIZED.

```
$newdbname = $env:NewDatabaseName

####################
$bytes = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($PSScriptRoot+"\Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices.dll")
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::Load($bytes)

$bytes = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($PSScriptRoot+"\Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServicesEnum.dll")
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::Load($bytes)

$bytes = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($PSScriptRoot+"\Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.Common.ObjectModel.dll")
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::Load($bytes)

$sqlConnectionString = "Data Source=xxx;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
$sqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection $sqlConnectionString
$SSISNamespace = "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices"
$SSIS = New-Object $SSISNamespace".IntegrationServices" $sqlConnection
$catalog = $SSIS.Catalogs["SSISDB"]


$newdbname = "["+$env:NewDatabaseName+"]"

$parameterValueConnectionString = "Data Source=xxxx;Initial Catalog="+$newdbname+";Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Auto Translate=False;Application Name=DevOps Auotmated Deploy"
$parameterValueInitialCatalogName = $newdbname
$parameterValueXMLPathValue = "\\Data.xml"

$ssisPackage = $catalog.Folders["SomeProject"].Projects["SomePackage"].Packages["Package.dtsx"]

$setValueParameters = New-Object 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices.PackageInfo+ExecutionValueParameterSet]';
$executionParameter = New-Object 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices.PackageInfo+ExecutionValueParameterSet';
$executionParameter.ObjectType = 50;
$executionParameter.ParameterName = "SYNCHRONIZED";
$executionParameter.ParameterValue = 1;
$setValueParameters.Add($executionParameter);

$executionParameter = New-Object 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices.PackageInfo+ExecutionValueParameterSet';
$executionParameter.ObjectType = 30;
$executionParameter.ParameterName = "ClientDB_ConnectionString";
$executionParameter.ParameterValue = $parameterValueConnectionString;
$setValueParameters.Add($executionParameter);

$executionParameter = New-Object 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices.PackageInfo+ExecutionValueParameterSet';
$executionParameter.ObjectType = 30;
$executionParameter.ParameterName = "CM.ClientDB.InitialCatalog";
$executionParameter.ParameterValue = $parameterValueInitialCatalogName;
$setValueParameters.Add($executionParameter);

$executionParameter = New-Object 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices.PackageInfo+ExecutionValueParameterSet';
$executionParameter.ObjectType = 30;
$executionParameter.ParameterName = "XMLPath";
$executionParameter.ParameterValue = $parameterValueXMLPathValue;
$setValueParameters.Add($executionParameter);

$ssisPackage.Execute("true", $null, $setValueParameters); 
   
Write-Output "Done"
```